# Mavericks PHPStorm error running git ... /usr/bin/git

Tags: git, phpstorm, osx-mavericks

I started PHPStorm in my newly updated OS X (Mavericks now).

Now in PHPStorm (also just updated btw) at the top right corner I get a message "error running git"

Answer (score 13):

If you get an error about PHPStorm not being able to run git you'll be given a "Fix it" link in that message window.

In the menu if you hit the Test button you'll get something about "Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges error" with an error code 69 (not sure if it was excactly that number... maybe someone wants to correct me).

What this means aka all you need to do is:

Run XCode and first thing it asks is to agree to the new iOS license.
Hit agree (and enter your password if requested), close XCode again, rerun PHPStorm, done.

Comment: Thanks I didn't have much to loose with that and you saved me precious minutes ! :)

Comment: And still the answer to the problem! Thanks!